# Extra blank line is getting printed at the end of the output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to read a file from command line and trying to `replace all the commas` in that file with blank. Below is my code:

```
import sys
datafile = sys.argv[1];

with open(datafile, 'r') as data:
  plaintext = data.read()

plaintext = plaintext.replace(',', '')
print(plaintext)
```

But while printing the plaintext I am getting `one extra blank row at the end`. Why is it happening and how can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use

```
plaintext.rstrip('\n')
```

This should remove the extra line

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine.